# Centering images in Tumblr Text Posts

Tags: html, css, image, tumblr

I am wanting to center large images for specific text based posted on my website. At present I have the following line of code:

```
.textpost img{float:left;margin:4px 15px 4px 0;min-width:250px;max-width:768px;border: transparent;}
```

In each text post, I include "width="250px" within the HTML of the text posts for the images, as a lot of posts are styled that way:

https://31.media.tumblr.com/045cf2e09852e860b5a2bd1ac68385e1/tumblr_inline_nl1t3uvkWz1qztcot.png

However we run interviews/features which require larger images.

I have been changing the width within the HTML of these text posts to "width="100%".

However this often makes the images look pixelated even when the images uploaded are greater than the width size. I believe Tumblr only allows a max width of 500px for images in texts post.

See here: https://31.media.tumblr.com/41ffeee4874a3b049f0f8f88b0e42a58/tumblr_inline_nl1t5rFHB11qztcot.png

When I change the coding to:

```
.textpost img{float:left;margin:4px 15px 4px 0;width:100%;border: transparent;}
```

The images appears how I want it to be but it effects all images in text posts, which I don't want it to do.

I have also considered creating a seperate line of code in the main website CSS for interview/feature text posts.

**I am wanting to center the image on these posts but it doesn't want to work, as the image still floats to the left.**

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Code used in website CSS:

```
.largeImage img{margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
```

HTML code used in Tumblr text post:

> ```
> <p class="largeImage"><img src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/2d502a864c683be80fec4a3ee05d8741/tumblr_inline_nl1rhtro5h1qztcot.jpg"></p>
> ```

I have also replaced the {PhotoURL-500} with {PhotoURL-HighRes} but I don't think this effects text posts.

Comment: Instead of add width 100%. Have you tried max-width: 100% on the images? Also can you post a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code?

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work as Tumblr doesn't allow images over 500px wide in Text posts. So I need to find out how to centre large images.

https://jsfiddle.net/esz5jcwk/2/

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/esz5jcwk/4/

Comment: What's been changed? I can't see any changes?

Comment: Image is center in the window.  Isn't that what you are looking for? Or am I confused?

Comment: Can you explain where and what you have changed so I can apply it to my personal code?

Comment: In the fiddle if you scroll down to the bottom. I put a comment where I change the styles.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve my issue. Images still float to left.

Comment: Do you it up on a server? For I can take a look.

Comment: It's hosted on Tumblr. The CSS is on Google Drive.

Comment: Is the css definitely being applied, I mean can you do body {background:red} to test. I didn't think files could be served from google drive. Also you want the image to be center aligned but presumably you want any text in the same container to be left aligned? There might be a hack using negative margins.